# asio buffer deep copy

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-asio

I have found the reference semantic of asio's buffer is not convenient in use. It requires user to allocate the data in heap, but for small size data(for example, 100 Byte), allocate on stack and copy it several times(I think the copy times should less than 3 when use asio）will be much faster than invoke a new operation.
For example:

```
class MyData {
    std::vector<char> data;
};

void hander(Request req) {
    MyData d;
    async_write(buffer(d.data)...);
} // oops, d was destroyed, but the actual write have not execute

// this is ok, but awkward and poor performance if data is very small
void hander(Request req) {
    shared_ptr<MyData> d(new MyData());
    async_write(buffer(d->data)...bind(&X::handle_write, this, d);
}
void handle_write(shared_ptr<MyData> s) {
}
```

Why asio have not provide a buffer which can do deep copy? It will save copy time for performance but for application send huge number small data, the performance should be worse

In its doc, connection object has a member used to do holding the data, but for most application, a data member is not enough. A queue need to use when the application can write data in any time(Don't like half-duplex protocol such as HTTP) or else data might be overwrited by next write. So if the queue is Queue, that still need to call new, if the queue is Queue, that still need to copy

Comment: You are not forced to use dynamically allocated data for the buffer, you just have to ensure that the lifetime of the data passed to the buffer will be long enough so that it doesn't go out of scope before the handler is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.Asio's buffer-types do not place any requirement as to where the actual memory needs to be allocated.  It simply requires that the memory for which it will represent be contiguous, and when it is not contiguous, then a buffer-sequence needs to be used.

Boost.Asio provides [`buffer_copy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_copy.html) which can be used to perform deep copies from one buffer or buffer sequence to another.  Pure speculation, but Asio may not provide a buffer that owns the underlying memory because:

- Memory usage characteristics vary between applications.  It is not apparent if there is a good *default* allocation or ownership strategy to use.
- `boost::buffer()` provides a convenient way to create Boost.Asio buffers from various types (raw memory, c-array, `boost/std::array`, `std::vector`, and `std::string`).  Some of these types already provide ways to customize allocation, as well as ways to perform deep-copies (copy-constructor, assignment, `std::copy`).
- Boost.Asio operations are implemented to the concept/type requirements of buffer sequences, such as  [MutableBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html), not the actual type, such as [`boost::asio::mutable_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffers_1.html).  Thus, users are free to use their own types and memory management, as long as it meets the type requirements.  Here is the official example of a [reference counted buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/buffers/reference_counted.cpp).

After profiling and identifying that allocations and copies are bottlenecks, then consider employing techniques designed to address specific problems:

- [Memory Pools](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) will allow for memory to be reused, rather than releasing memory back to the free store.
- In some cases, reference counting buffers may remove the need to perform deep-copies.  Consider using the official example or `boost/std::shared_ptr`.  These can even be used by types managed by a pool through the use of a custom deleter.
- For unique ownership, `std::unique_ptr` and/or move-semantics may also remove unnecessary deep-copies.

Comment: buffer_copy in this situation is useless if the dest still alloc on stack.

Comment: @jean There are situations where _all_ functions are useless, but it does not imply the function is useless _all_ the time.  I have used `buffer_copy` to deep-copy caller provided memory to stack-based memory, allowing the caller to reuse memory as I perform a synchronous operation.

Comment: yeah...I have to say that the goal of asio design are more stress on all-purpose with a little lose of convenient

Answer (score 0):

ASIO does not provide such buffer class, but it is feasible to write an own one. Also the [Buffers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/buffers/reference_counted.cpp) example has an implementation of such class.

To increase performance, it is possible to organize a pool, for instance, the [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) library uses [its own message pool](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/tree/master/websocketpp/message_buffer).